# android internal storage folders when running simulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am testing how to create directories using internal storage, but how to see in eclipse if this folder was properly created? where is this folder created when executing simulator? Thank you

```
public class DirectoriesActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        createFolder(getBaseContext());

    }

    public static void createFolder(Context context){

            context.getDir("aplicaciones", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working in eclipse then you can see the complete file structure of installed app folder.

step 1: go to Windows->show view->android->file explorer

step 2 : expand directory data->data-> app installed package-> Here you can see created folders

Answer (score 0):

Go to DDMSView-> FileExplorer->data->data->your package ->files